# Android Camera2 - FLASH_MODE_TORCH not working with CONTROL_MODE_OFF on some devices (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S8)

Tags: android, torch, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

I am creating a continuous capture session with the Torch enabled:

```
  captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, new Range(Framerate, Framerate));
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE));
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 100000L);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, 66666666L);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 1000);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(), callback, null);
```

It works well on many devices but on some others (for example the Samsung Galaxy S8), `FLASH_MODE_TORCH` seems to trigger some internal code which then overrides my `CONTROL_MODE_OFF`.

I can test this by checking the sensor value of the resulting frames:

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback callback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
            RealSensorSentivity = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY);
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        }
    };
```

Instead of getting `1000`, I always get `64`.

If I remove the `FLASH_MODE_TORCH` parameter, everything (except the torch) works well.

I tried to use the Camera1 API together with this and that didn't work. Also tried using the newer:

```
manager.setTorchMode(camId, true);
```

But that fails as the camera is already in use (weird).

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the main issue was:

`mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);`

Devices have wildy different settings for this.

I fixed it by using:

`mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);`

Comment: hey, is there any way i can see your full code/

Comment: No, it's not possible but if the problem is similar, I can try to give some tips.

Comment: I need to set ISO 100 while keeping the flash mode as touch

Comment: As soon as I do AE_MODE_OFF, the touch gets off.

Comment: Try to go full manual as I did and also check whether the camera/device you are using supports that combination.

Comment: It just my phone doesn't support this, but I am able to set ISO manually with torch in openCamera application